# Using prevAll to select all sections of a table containing a keyword

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9czm7g3y/1/) with the relevant table HTML.

I want to use jQuery to highlight or remove sections of a table if they contain certain keywords.

```
<table>
    <tr class="mark"></tr>
    <tr><td>apple</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>

    <tr class="mark"></tr>
    <tr><td>pear</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>

    <tr class="mark"></tr>
    <tr><td>apple</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>

    <tr class="mark"></tr>
    <tr><td>pear</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>

    <tr class="mark"></tr>
    <tr><td>apple</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>

    <tr class="mark"></tr>
    <tr><td>pear</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>

    <tr class="mark"></tr>
    <tr><td>apple</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Right now, I can use

```
$("td:contains('pear')").parent().prev().nextUntil(".mark").css("background-color", "red");
```

to accomplish what I want to do (highlight all sections, delimited by `===`, that contain "pear"). But how can I do this with `prevAll` for the cases where the delimiter row isn't directly previous to the text I'm searching for? I tried `$("td:contains('pear')").parent().prevAll(".mark:first").nextUntil(".mark").css("background-color", "red");` which I think should work, but only one section is highlighted. I think I'm missing a key piece of understanding about how jQuery deals with situations where I want to map actions like `prevAll()` to a list of elements.

Please ignore the bad table layout; this is simply what I have to work with T_T

Comment: Maybe have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("td:contains('pear')").parent().each(function() {
  $(this).prevAll(".mark:first").nextUntil(".mark").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/aszepeshazi/9czm7g3y/2/

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I wanted. I'm very new to jQuery and had no idea `each()` existed. Thank you!